# IOS sharing through email,message causing view controller to change look

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS.
I managed to implement the share function, but it is causing an issue with the view controller. The top part is like hidden, but still exists there.

Here is a screenshots when opening the view controller

[image: When opening the viewcontroller]

Here is a screenshot after i select share to message or mail:

[image: after sharing or canceling]

Even though the top is not showing, i can still press the home button.

Can anyone help me with this? how to solve to leave the look as it is?
and this is happening only with message and mail, i tried Facebook, linked, viber, whatsup, this doesn't happen.

if anyone needs any source code, i can provide you.

*** EDIT ***
Here is the code that i have for calling the sharing functionality:

```
   PayoffItem *item = [((PayoffDoc*)self.payoffsHistory[indexPath.row]) payoffItem];
    NSString *subtitle = item.subtitle;
    NSString *title = item.title;
    if(title != nil){
    title = [title stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
        if(subtitle != nil)
            title = [title stringByAppendingString:subtitle];
    }
    NSString *url1 = item.content;
    NSString *shareText = @"";
    if(title != nil)
        shareText = [title stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    else
        shareText = @"Sharing from Alleview";
    //NSString *shareText = @"TEsting ";
    if(url1 != nil)
    shareText = [shareText stringByAppendingString:url1];
    NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareText];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I don't have any code implemented for dismissing the sharing.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code that presents and dismisses the share sheet?

Comment: i updated my question, with the relevant code for the sharing functionality.

Comment: Scott Bossak, any chance you can help with the problem?